# ReactJS - Display all files in Firebase storage on UI in a list

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a ReactJS application that allows a user to choose a file using File Uploader and upload it to Firebase Storage (not Database). These uploads are stored in a directory called 'sorts'. The user can upload a PDF, image, a WebM, etc. I'm trying to list all files found in storage on the UI but I am having issues. I think there is a way to do it with Firebase Database but not too sure if it's possible with Firebase Storage. I've tried following the documentation [download files via web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) but I couldn't really get it working. Most of what I've found online is only displaying one file from storage, not a list of all the files. At the moment, I am able to get a list of the download URLs for each file in the form of: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/algorithms-visualiser-react.appspot.com/o/sorts%2Fvideo_956493.webm?alt=media&token=07b18ccf-3e3d-4a1f-88b5-193528f0cf09. Issue comes when I try to list all these on the actual UI (whether that be an actual visual representation of each file or simply a list of all the downlad URLs which, when clicked on, would download the file).

Below is the relevant code:

- Uploading:

  ```
  handleUploadStart = () => {
     this.setState ({
        progress: 0
      })
  }

  handleUploadSuccess = filename => {
     this.setState ({
       sort: filename, 
       progress: 100
     })

     firebase.storage().ref('sorts').child(filename).getDownloadURL()
     .then(url => this.setState ({
       videoURL: url
     }))
  }
  ```
- Render function (includes how each download link is retrieved and how files are uploaded)

  ```
  render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  console.log(this.state);

  var i = 0;
  let displayFile = '';
  const sorts = [];
  $('#Sorts').find('tbody').html('');

  firebase.storage().ref().child('sorts/').listAll().then(function(result) {
      result.items.forEach(function(fileRef) {
          i++; // Counter for each file in storage

          fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(fileURL) {
              console.log(fileURL);
              sorts.push(fileURL);
          })
      });
  });

  return (
  <div className="App">
      <SortsToolbar history={this.props.history} />
      <FileUploader 
      accept="*"
      name="video"
      storageRef={firebase.storage().ref('sorts')} 
      onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
      onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess} />
      <br />
      {sorts.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
  </div>
  );
  }
  ```

As mentioned, if I could simply find a way to list all these download links in a list on the UI side, it'd be something. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`getDownloadURL` is the only way to get a URL from a file in Cloud Storage, and it only works on one file at a time.  There is no bulk operation for this.

You can try to list the files you want with the [list API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files), but you will still have to iterate that list and call `getDownloadURL` on each one of them.

For tasks like this, storing the URLs in a database and query that is typically the easier and faster way to go.

Comment: I found a video showing how to list all files in storage using HTML and Javascipt (which works). At the moment, I'm using React HTML Parser to display this list on a React page. Weird how doing the same thing in React seems like a much more daunting task.

Comment: Storing the URL doesn't seem to be a great solution unless the storage is public. For private files you'll need a token to access them and that token expires after some time, so storing the file URL with the token also won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to get urls without using `getDownloadURL`. What I am doing is using a list from storage reference of the required folder, then adding the needed prefixes instead of slash which firebase needs. Therefore, without using `getDownloadURL` I am getting all the urls.

```
storageRef.listAll().then(function (result) {
            let path = storageRef.fullPath
            path = path.replace(/\b\/\b(?!.*?\b\/\b)/, "%2F");
            result.items.forEach(fileRef => {
                temp.push({name:  fileRef.name, url: path + "%2F" + fileRef.name +"?alt=media"  })
            });
        }).then(()=>{
        
            // set data in your any state variable for later use
            setData(temp)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```